# MySQL FIND_IN_SET returning empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query where I am trying to find a matching tag from a comma separated value in a db Table, the value in the database may look like this:

```
"Tags":"all, kids, family, cqr, october"
```

and my query right now looks like this:

```
$rows = $db -> select("
    SELECT `FriendlyId`,`Name`,`Description`,`Tags`,`BeginDate`,`EndDate` 
    FROM  `Pages` 
    WHERE `SiteId` =  '569e435701395' 
    AND `IsActive` =  '1' 
    AND `BeginDate` IS NOT NULL 
    AND FIND_IN_SET('kids', Tags)
    ORDER BY  `BeginDate` ASC");
```

Unfortunately, this is returning an empty result even though I know there are rows in the db that match the query. This is my first time ever using `FIND_IN_SET` so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where is your `where` keyword?

Comment: whoops, when I didnt go back far enough in the undo's fixed now.

Comment: The value is seen as `' kids'` with a leading space, you would need to deal with that. I doubt it would ever find `'all'` - You need to use a different approach or fix the database so it is not breaking the cardinal rule of using delimited textual data.

Comment: @ravisachaniya : yes you saw it after edit

Comment: @AlexK. my options are limited in terms of "fixing the database" as it's tied to a CMS, however adding a leading space in front of the keyword fixed the issue.